# Display week number in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to show the week number of month in mysql and currently I can get the week number of year when executing this query. I'm retrieving results per week and need to display the week number (as 1st week of January, 2nd week of January. 3rd week of January, etc). Can any body please help me to do this?

```
SELECT  d.draftID_PK,
          d.clientID_FK,
          count(d.quoteNr) AS totalquote,
          DATE_FORMAT (d.draftDate,'%u  %M %Y') as draftDate,
          c.clientName
FROM draft d
INNER JOIN client c ON c.clientID_PK = d.clientId_FK
WHERE   d.draftDate<CURDATE() AND d.draftDate>'2013-01-05'
        AND c.clientName = '{$client_name}' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT (d.draftDate,'%u')
ORDER BY d.draftDate DESC
```

Comment: I believe you looking for this
http://think-robot.com/2009/04/week-of-the-month-in-mysql/

Comment: See the comments section of this page (very near the bottom) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

I made something, maybe this can help you but the number of weeks varies according to the week begins, example:
Here in Brazil, the week starts in Sunday. So take a look if this can solve your problem.

```
SET @date:='2014-08-31';
SELECT 
    @first := date_add(
        date_add(
            LAST_DAY(@date),
            interval 1 DAY
        ),
        interval -1 MONTH
    ) AS first_day,
    @date,
    -- EXAMPLE 1
    WeekofYear(@date),
    WeekofYear(@first),
    WeekofYear(@date)-(WeekofYear(@first)-1) Num_Week,
    -- EXAPLE 2 - Works in Brazil perfectly
    Week(@date),
    Week(@first),
    Week(@date)-(Week(@first)-1) Num_Week_Brazil
```